# Autenticacion mediante un esquema OAuth utilizando Javascrit

Tags: javascript, api, cors

Un software contable en la nube permite realizar consumo de API. Ellos me enviaron el token con el Usuario API y la Access Key. Estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open("POST", "https://api.prueba.com/auth");

request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log("Status:", this.status);
    console.log("Headers:", this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log("Body:", this.responseText);
  }
};

var body = {
  username: "micorreo@gmail.com",
  access_key:
    "M2I0NjRlxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
};

request.send(JSON.stringify(body));
```

**Pero aparece error con el cors.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como puedo corregir este error o quien me puede orientar para tratar este caso. Muchas gracias y Bendiciones para todos. **Nota**: Soy nuevo en programación.

Feliz día.

Comment: En ese caso debes pedirles a ellos que permitan acceder desde tu dominio. Y como recomendación nunca publiques tus api keybni tus contraseñas en internet. Usa [edit] y cambialo por otros datos de prueba

Comment: Perfecto, Muchas gracias

Comment: Ojo, lo mas seguro es que no esté permitido el consumo de esa API desde el cliente, o sea, en el navegador. Es lo más lógico por seguridad, ya que tus credenciales *(access_key, username)* pueden ser fácilmente filtradas. Lo más recomendable es que lo hagas desde tu servidor *(backend)*, añadiendo así una especie de filtro